# By directional integration with java atmosphere(wasync) from .net Client application

Tags: networking, websocket, atmosphere, websocket4net

We have a `atmosphere(wasync)` server Application which is written in java and I want to communicate with `.net` thick client application using `websocket4Net`.

I am able to achieve the communication if the server and client are in both `.net`  environment.

The issue appears when I try to connect to java `atmosphere(wasync)` with URL:

`ws://myHostName:1010/atmosphere_server/atmos/broadcost`

then I am getting an exception: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After using WebSocket4Net.dll version 0.9.0.0 along with AtmosphereWebSocket4Net.dll now we are able to connect to java atmosphere(wasync) from .net Client application  also we are able to receive the message from java application. But the message which we have sent is not getting received in java application.

The latest version of WebSocket4Net.dll is 0.14.0.0, tried to include this in the application, but getting compile errors for "Rfc6455Processor" interface. Whether the latest version of WebSocket4Net.dll is not supported for AtmosphereWebSocket ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!